# from an MVC 4.0 ActionFilterAttribute how do I get the current ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the current ApiController from the filterContext.  It exposes a controller property but the ApiController implements some httpcontroller interface and is not there.

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

Comment: nm.  They have two attributes with the same name.  The one in the other namespace works.                    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

Answer (score 2):

You would cast it back to your ApiController. Something like this:

```
var apiController = filterContext.Controller as ApiController;
if (apiController != null)
{
    //Do something with apiController.
}
```